# How to parse list of list of objects in java

Tags: java, collections

I am working on an application and in one of the scenarios, backend returns a list of list of objects which needs to be parsed. Below are the classes present.

```
class A {
}
class B extends A {
public int shape;
}
class D extends B {
public int time;
}
class C extends A {
public List<List<B>> listOfLists;
}
```

So basically if its square, shape will be 10 and there wont be duration.
If its circle, shape will be 360 and duration will be 20. These needs to be parsed in the application based on the listOfList returned by the backend. So the question is how to parse listOfLists to figure out the shape and duration?

Comment: Are we assuming that `listOfLists` is a multi-element list of other multi-element lists?

Comment: `listOfLists = [[{shape: "type", time: "duration"}]];`: that is not valid Java. You're asking how to parse, but parse what? `listOfLists` is a list of lists of B. There's nothing to parse.

Comment: Its basically a list of list of objects. Object can be either of type B or D

Comment: @JB Nizet: I have just shown how listOfLists looks like.

Comment: OK. But what is your question? As I said: there is nothing to parse here. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: You can check the type of each element with the instanceof keyword and then casting

Comment: What type of program is this for? What is your high-level goal?

Comment: @qxz: I have updated the question. Please take a look.

Comment: Figure out the shape and duration of what? The first one? All of them? What are you doing with the obtained information? Are you using a specific library which is returning the list of lists?

Comment: @qxz: To brief you about the app, if the duration is present then that particular shape will be shown only for that amount of time. If there is no duration present then that shape will be shown forever.

Comment: So what is your goal with the list of lists? Extract a non-nested `List<B>`? Perform some action with each `B`? Please edit your question to include this info.

Comment: @qxz: Say if i receive shape as Circle, I need to perform some geometric computation related to circle and proceed further. Same is the case for other shapes. This implies that there is a need to parse the objects and figure out the shape.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is a bit unclear about what exactly you are trying to do. If you want to perform some action with each `B` in the `List<List<B>>`, you can just use two nested `for` loops:

```
List<List<B>> listOfLists;
for (List<B> list : listOfLists) {
    for (B b : list) {
        int shape = b.shape;
        int time = -1;
        if (b instanceof D) time = ((D)b).time;
        // do something with shape and time...
    }
}
```